# for loops and if statement error occuring

Tags: java

I can't figure out why I get the error:

`java.util.NoSuchElementException null(in java.util.Scanner)`

in my method:

```
public void processTransactions(Scanner transFile){

        while (transFile.hasNext()){
           for(i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
               finalInventory[i] = startingInventory[i];

               if(ids[i] == transFile.next()){
                   finalInventory[i] += transFile.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my construtor:

```
public SoftDrinkInventory(Scanner inventoryFile) {

        initializeString(names);
        initializeString(ids);
        initializeInt(startingInventory);
        initializeInt(finalInventory);
        initializeInt(transactionCounts);

        while (inventoryFile.hasNext()){
            names[i] = inventoryFile.next();
            ids[i] = inventoryFile.next();
            startingInventory[i] = inventoryFile.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
    }
```

All variables have been declared previously in the class.

Comment: What happens if your scanner runs out of input during one iteration of the `for` loop?

Comment: You are writing this transFile.nextInt(); twice........if(ids[i] == transFile.next()){ finalInventory[i] += transFile.nextInt();} which moves the controller to last + 1 element when the controller is at last element

Comment: oh .. missed that .. thanks @DavidWallace

Comment: Which line throws the Exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing a little, but I think your code was supposed to be this.

```
public void processTransactions(Scanner transFile){

    while (transFile.hasNext()){
       String key = transFile.next();
       int value = transFile.nextInt();
       for(i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
           finalInventory[i] = startingInventory[i];

           if(ids[i].equals(key)){
               finalInventory[i] += value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You only want to do the `next()` and the `nextInt()` once per iteration of the `while` loop.  Currently, you are repeating the `next()` in every iteration of the `for` loop, which really isn't what you want.

Note that this isn't the most efficient solution to your problem, but it *will* take away your error.

Also, you haven't specified the type of `ids`, but I've assumed that it's a `String[]`.

Comment: +1 But we have no idea what format the file is, or if it should fail fast (or just log and continue).

Comment: Yes, but it's obvious from the question that the file has some kind of key (which I guess isn't necessarily a `String`, but may as well be), and that each key is followed by an integer that has to be "added on" to an inventory count.  This answer may be incorrect in some of the details that haven't been supplied, but it is "close enough" to get OP up and running again.

Comment: It's working so far. I'll repost if I can't figure out what I need to do next. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `hasNext()` but using `nextInt()` ... One solution is to use,

```
 while (transFile.hasNextInt()){
   // As before.
 }
```

Another is to skip anything that isn't an `int`, perhaps like so

```
while (transFile.hasNext()){
  if (!transFile.hasNextInt()) {
    transFile.next();
    continue;
  }
  // As before.
}
```

Comment: No, the next call after `hasNext()` is `next()`, not `nextInt()`.  I believe you have misdiagnosed this.  However, I shan't downvote, because the question is absolutely not clear.